# Laravel: How to "order by" using Eloquent with function($query)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

Simple question - how do I order by 'id' in this, is'nt work

```
        $servico = Servico::with([
            'example1',
            'etapas' => function ($query) {
                $query->orderBy('id', 'asc');
            },
            'example2'])
        ->first();
```

I trying order by id or other data, but don't work.

Comment: remove the `=>function ... ` from the `with()`, and after with add `->whereHas('etapas' => function ($q) { $q->orderBy('id', 'asc'); })`

Comment: @geertjanknapen `->whereHas()` performs an `EXISTS(...)` query, but doesn't actually return anything, so using that and supplying an `orderBy()` doesn't make any sense...  `->with()` is the correct function here.

Comment: whereHas() does not return anything, except when the with() is also supplied, or using the withWhereHas() method.